# How to use hyph-utf8 correctly?

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex, hyphenation

I'm using MiKTeX and pdfLaTeX and the package manager tells me that `hyph-utf8` is installed and auto-download of packages is activated, too.

But when I do `\usepackage{hyph-utf8}`, because I hope that it will correct some currently wrong german hyphenations in my documents, I only get a warning about a missing `hyph-utf8.sty` file.

Did I understand the purpose of `hyph-utf8` correct ("provide more hyphenation patterns for words in many languages") and do I try to use it correctly (`\usepackage{hyph-utf8}`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hyph-utf8` is simply a collection of pattern files, not a package you load. If you want the experimental german patterns you need the `dehyph-exptl` package. Its documentation shows you how to use it. You will perhaps have to activate the patterns in miktex-settings in the language tab. Then this document

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\showhyphens{löste Fassade modernste Abendstern Mordopfer}
\end{document}
```

should give in the log-file

```
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 lös-te Fas-sa-de mo-derns-te Abend-stern Mord-op-fer
```

Comment: Thanks. This means using `babel` automatically loads the `hyph-utf8` patterns as long as I don't change it by loading a package with alternative patterns?

Comment: babel will use the patterns set up in languages.ini/in the language tab of miktex settings. For most languages these are nowadays the patterns from hyph-utf8.

Comment: Hmm, everything works fine here with a different loading order (as always in comments no linebreaks): `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{hyphsubst} \HyphSubstIfExists{ngerman-x-latest}{\HyphSubstLet{ngerman}{ngerman-x-latest}}{} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: dehyph-exptl and hyphsubst works only with XeTeX and pdfLaTeX.