# How to use the 'usenglishmax' hyphenation patterns from hyph-utf8? (pdfLaTeX, TeXLive, ubuntu)

Tags: pdftex, texlive, hyphenation

I am using `pdfLaTeX` from `TeXLive` on `Kubuntu` 20.04. Suppose that the LaTeX document I am writing is entirely in U.S. English.

How can I use the `usenglishmax` hyphenation patterns (which are mentioned at the end of [this](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/README)) from [`hyph-utf8`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyph-utf8)? Does one use it in conjunction with [`hyphsubst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphsubst)? Does one need to use `babel`, even if the entire text is in U.S. English?

I find the documentation quite unclear.

In particular, is the following the correct usage?
(This is adapted from the Speravir's comments to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104377/192504).)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{hyphsubst} 
\HyphSubstIfExists{hyph-en-us}{\HyphSubstLet{english}{hyph-en-us}}{}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}

% just for testing purposes, let's set these to zero
\lefthyphenmin=0
\righthyphenmin=0
% must be done after \begin{document}, because it seems 'babel'
% sets these at that point
%
% The defaults for U.S. English are  
% \lefthyphenmin=2 and \righthyphenmin=3

\thispagestyle{empty}

% testing on the first ten entries from the
% 2021 version of ushyphex.tex
% (https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenex)

\begin{checkhyphens}{}
academy academies accusative acronym acronyms
acupuncture acupuncturist adamant addable addible
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

Lastly, on what words can I test it (say, using the package [`testhyphens`](https://ctan.org/pkg/testhyphens))? In other words, what are some words that get hyphenated with `usenglishmax` that are not hyphenated in a LaTeX document that doesn't use `usenglishmax`?

For what it's worth, in the example above, all ten words get hyphenated that same regardless of whether the lines

```
\usepackage{hyphsubst} 
\HyphSubstIfExists{hyph-en-us}{\HyphSubstLet{english}{hyph-en-us}}{}
```

are commented out or not.

On the other hand, if the line `\usepackage[english]{babel}` is also commented out, then some of the words get hyphenated differently.

**Appendix:**

[image]

Comment: You never, for English, want to set `\righthyphenmin=0` or `1`, as you will get really bad results as shown for "adaman-t" as shown in @egreg`s answer.  The same is true for `\lefthyphenmin`.  What you refer to as `usenglishmax` is not based on patterns, but is a list of annotated exceptions that are *not* hyphenated properly by the patterns.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your comment and clarification (and for all your work on the hyphenation exception list)! Indeed, I generally don't mess with the default values of `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`; the above was only for testing purposes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But while I have you here (so to speak), do you happen to know why you and your colleagues decided to disallow the first breakpoint in 'ac-ro-nym'? (I know that 'Some other permissible hyphens have been omitted for reasons of style or clarity.' But what is wrong with 'ac-ronym'?)

Comment: That's a good question, and my guess is that either it wasn't marked in the hyphenated corpus used to derive the patterns (or wasn't there), or has been inhibited by something else.  To test the latter conjecture, I've tested "homonym", "synonym" and "retronym".  The only hyphen added by the patterns is in "syn-onym".  I'll do a dictionary check.  (May take several days.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you! By the way, all three volumes of *Webster's Third New International Dictionary of the English Language, Unabridged* are available on `archive.org`; if you have archive.org's free account, you can 'borrow' each volume for an hour at a time. Links: [Vol. 1 (A-G)](https://archive.org/details/webstersthirdnew01gove), [Vol. 2 (H-R)](https://archive.org/details/webstersthirdnew0002unse/mode/2up), and [Vol. 3 (S-Z)](https://archive.org/details/webstersthirdnew0003unse/mode/2up).  I have included a screenshot in my question as an appendix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the language name; mentioning the hyphenation pattern file is useless.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphsubst}

\HyphSubstLet{english}{usenglishmax}

\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}

\lefthyphenmin=0
\righthyphenmin=0

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{checkhyphens}{}
academy academies accusative acronym acronyms
acupuncture acupuncturist adamant addable addible
algebraically
antiderivative
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment the substitution line, I get

[image]

Thus you see that new patterns are used. Still, you're not guaranteed to get everything is in the hyphenation exception list `ushyphex.tex`.

With

```
\HyphSubstLet{english}{usenglishmax}
\input{ushyphex}
```

one gets

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get `! Package hyphsubst Error: Unknown pattern 'usenglishmax'.` When I run `tex --version`, I get `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` and `kpathsea version 6.3.1`.

Comment: (But it does work on Overleaf.)

Comment: @linguisticturn Oh, it seems you don't have a *full* TeX Live. You should install the relevant Debian package, which should be `texlive-lang-english`

Comment: That did it. Thanks!