Why are dehyph, elhyphen, ruhyphen, and ukrhyph required packages?
Since my document is not written in German, I thought I would uninstall the dehyph package.
But apparently this package is required when running pdfLaTeX.  Why?  What does it contain that it is so essential?
I am using a MikTeX system in Windows 10, if it makes a difference.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Testing test test.
\end{document}

When I run pdfLaTeX on this file, I get a prompt from MikTeX that I am missing the dehypht.tex file found in the dehyph package.  When I decline to install it, I get the following error message "... pdflatex.exe did not succeed."
Interestingly enough, if I run the same file with XeLaTeX the file compiles fine.
UPDATE The same is true for elhyphen (Greek hyphenation patterns), ruhyphen (Russian hyphenation patterns), and ukrhyph (Ukranian hyphenation patterns).
UPDATE2 I just realized that I asked almost essentially the same question a few years back: Why does the original LaTeX need hyphenation patterns for German, Coptic, Greek, Ukrainian, and Russian in order to process a file?.  That question was recently answered, so I am tempted to delete this one, unless people think that the different phrasing of the question has value.

Please share your document code as MWE

'Required' by what exactly?

Maybe this old question might give you some insight: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104367/how-to-use-hyph-utf8-correctly

When you run the MWE, what happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact error message?

If possible, please post your .log file details

That's not a package in the usual sense, but an installation package with hyphenation patterns. These must be present when the format is built, and I guess the default installation of MikTeX is to generate the format with all hyphenation patterns. XeTeX doesn't use these. I'm sure you can tweak MikTeX not to look fro German hyphenation patterns when building the format but it's not worth the trouble.

I asked tlmgr for information about those packages (MiKTeX has no tlmgr, but the sizes are the same). I omit the longdesc field, that's irrelevant, because we're interested in the size.
> tlmgr info dehyph hyphen-greek ruhyphen ukrhyph

package:     dehyph
category:    Package
shortdesc:   German hyphenation patterns for traditional orthography
longdesc:    [...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    48599
sizes:       run: 229k
relocatable: No
cat-license: lppl1
cat-topics:  german hyphenation
collection:  collection-langgerman

package:     hyphen-greek
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   Modern Greek hyphenation patterns.
longdesc:    [...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    58652
sizes:       doc: 1853k, run: 81k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 5
cat-license: other-free
cat-topics:  greek hyphenation
collection:  collection-langgreek

package:     ruhyphen
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Russian hyphenation
longdesc:    [...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    21081
sizes:       src: 61k, run: 249k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.6
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  hyphenation russian
collection:  collection-langcyrillic

package:     ukrhyph
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Hyphenation Patterns for Ukrainian
longdesc:    A range of patterns, depending on the encoding of the output font (including the standard T2A, so one can use the patterns with free fonts).
installed:   Yes
revision:    21081
sizes:       doc: 293k, run: 181k
relocatable: No
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  hyphenation ukrainian
collection:  collection-langcyrillic

Thus you see that the space occupied on disk by the four packages is 2947k, short of three megabytes.
Do you think that it's worth the pain of editing the language.dat file and recreating formats? And to undo the work in case you happen to need German, Russian, Ukrainian or Greek in one of your documents?
